# Filter on Group By dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm, datagrid

I'm working on WPF - MVVM Application.

I have a dataGrid populated by invoices filtered by a textbox that works fine.

Now, I grouped the invoices by Invoice Number (suppInvNumber), and the filter doesn't work anymore.

How can I make it work?

## **ViewModel**

```
public class ConsultInvoiceViewModel:ViewModelBase
    {
        public Context ctx = new Context();

        private ICollectionView _dataGridCollection;
        private string _filterString;
        private ObservableCollection<Invoice> invoiceCollection; 

        public ConsultInvoiceViewModel()
        {
            DataGridCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Get());
            DataGridCollection.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Filter);
        }

        public ICollectionView DataGridCollection
        {
            get
            { 
                return _dataGridCollection; 
            }
            set 
            { 
                _dataGridCollection = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("DataGridCollection"); }
        }

        public string FilterString
        {
            get 
            { 
                return _filterString; 
            }
            set 
            {
                _filterString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FilterString");
                FilterCollection();
            }
        }

        private void FilterCollection()
        {
            if (_dataGridCollection != null)
            {
                _dataGridCollection.Refresh();
            }
        }

        public bool Filter(object obj)
        {
            var data = obj as Invoice;
            if (data != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filterString))
                {
                    return data.suppInvNumber.Contains(_filterString)

                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


        private ObservableCollection<Invoice> Get()
        {
            var query = ctx.Invoices
                        .GroupBy(x => new { x.suppInvNumber, x.shop1, x.date, x.foodSupplier })
                        .ToList()
                        .Select(i => new Invoice
                        {
                            suppInvNumber = i.Key.suppInvNumber,
                            shop1 = i.Key.shop1,
                            date = i.Key.date,
                            foodSupplier = i.Key.foodSupplier,
                            totalPrice = i.Sum(t => t.totalPrice),
                        })
                        .AsQueryable();

            invoiceCollection = new ObservableCollection<Invoice>(query);
            return invoiceCollection;
        }
}
```

Comment: I doubt if the above logic works !! I don't see a link between FilterString Changed & Filter().

Comment: @Nikita he calls `_dataGridCollection.Refresh()` in the setter of `FilterString`. That will re-create the view of course with the affect of the current Filter.

Comment: Do you see the data shown? it's grouped OK but not sorted?

Comment: yes, I can see them. No I didn't sorted yet. Will it help?

Comment: @KingKing I saw that but _datagridColl.Refresh() will never call DataGridCollection's Filter to reeveluated.

Comment: @Nikita, without grouping by, my filter works fine.

Comment: @Cantinou So you got records(grouped) in Get() but it is not filtered on SuppInvNumber?

Comment: Exactly, It's doesn't filter anymore.

Comment: @Cantinou thats really strange !! lemme try it in sample & I'll get back to you

Comment: @Cantinou I tried out similar sample & it works fine for me !!! just check if it has filter & not refreshing the UI.

Comment: OK, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nikita `_datagridColl.Refresh()` will re-create the view, internally the `Filter` will be executed to determine which items are included in the view. It's a callback. Of course you don't call that callback yourself.

Comment: @KingKing please correct me if I am wrong.. the Filter is set on the property DataGridCollection & not on the private variable, so theres no way property will get refreshed by refreshing the underlying variable.

Comment: @Nikita `DataGridCollection` is a property, it is just a wrapper of the backing field (which you call private variable). So `_datagridColl.Refresh()` is the same as `DataGridCollection.Refresh()` - the `Filter` is held by that reference and it knows about that Filter, so internally it can call that callback (in a loop) to determine which items are added to the view, if the callback returns `true` for the item passed-in, that item will be added to the view, otherwise that item will be excluded. That's how filtering works.

Comment: @KingKing Thanks for the explaination !! really helped.